# MICROSOFT EXCEL 2010: Reference One Cell Value To Get Row #

Tags: excel, excel-2010

## Is there any possible way to get a certain row value by using the value of different cell?

For example: My current cell information is

```
=Estimates!R6C12
```

It is referencing a different sheet with the value of Row 6 and Column 12.

Now for each month I copy the previous months data, however I would like to be able to change just that single cell based on cell [Like Row# = ? ]

Is there any way to do this? Something like this?

```
=Estimates!R(R[-21]C])C10
```

Comment: Formula shouldn't change if you insert data?

Comment: It does because i have an estimate of the money I will be making on Sheet 2 (estimates) that is referenced on sheet 1 (summary). 

So for instance in sheet 2 (estimates), January Is row 1. It includes the various variables for that specific month.

Now in sheet 1 (summary) I have each month Showing how much money I am gonna be making and how much budget I have based on the variables in Sheet 2. Since each month I am using a different row on sheet 2, the value formula would change.

Comment: Still don't understand. I mean, when you drag the formula down, excel increments row automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear, but it sounds like you might want to use the INDIRECT() formula.

```
=INDIRECT("Estimates!R"&ROW([reference])&"C10",false)
```

Then the row would be the row of a reference cell, and the column would be 10.

Comment: You can use the code formatting options to format your answers to make it easier to stand out.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! Never knew about that function. I have been going back and fixing the value of 20 different cells to fix the reference. This is gonna save me a little time each paycheck! Thank you Neil!

Answer (score 1):

INDIRECT is a volatile function and should never be used. INDEX works just as well and is not volatile.

```
=INDEX(Estimates!$A$1:$Z$25,6,12)
```